# Checkboxes and radio buttons will not save for display in CIVICRM backend - Joomla

Tags: joomla

We are running Joomla! version 3.10.6 (the latest stable version). We have in there CiviCRM 5.46.2 (also the latest stable version). There are two issues:

ONE: All checkbox fields do not retain the checkmark after you click on Save and go back to that page. If I edit an event or I change the settings on the "Debugging and Error Handling" page and then go back in and view what I just saved, the checkmarks that I just put in are gone from the display. They appear to be saving in the database, just not on the display.

TWO: With Enable Debugging enabled I see warnings like this:

```
 Notice: Undefined index: localTasks in /home/mysite/www/www/media/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%EA/EAA/EAA96A89%%joomla.tpl.php on line 56
```

and this on the sidebar:

```
 Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/mysite/www/www/media/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%ED/ED0/ED0373F0%%blocks.tpl.php on line 11
```

We have cleared caches but these warnings remain.

This site is hosted by CiviHosting and runs PHP 7.4

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This was a freshly-migrated site. Seems the database export from the other host was faulted. Using Akeeba to migrate the files and the database worked and the problem is fixed.